# Error Making Entity Relationship Encodable/ Decodable

Tags: core-data, swift4, codable, decodable, encodable

**How to encode/decode NSOrderedSet variable in swift4 codable while mapping with coredata NSManagedObject?**

```
import CoreData
import Foundation

@objc(TestObject)
public class TestObject:NSManagedObject,Encodable
{

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<TestObject> {
    return NSFetchRequest<TestObject>(entityName: "TestObject")
}


@NSManaged public var testName: String?
@NSManaged public var devices: NSOrderedSet?  // of entity type "Device"

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case testName
    case devices

}
public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
     var container = encoder.container(keyedBy:CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(testName,forKey:.testName)
    try container.encode(devices,forKey:.devices)
}
}

public required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.decode(testName,forKey:.testName)
    try container.decode(devices,forKey:.devices)

}
```

It Gives error : 
Compiler gives this error

```
No 'decode' candidates produce the expected contextual result type 'NSOrderedSet?'
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by taking advantage of one of the auto-generated accessors.

```
//addToDevices(_ value: Device) 

public required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.testName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .testName)
    let devices = try container.decode([Device].self, forKey:.devices)
    devices.forEach { self.addToDevices($0) }
}
```

If you don't have the auto-generated accessors follow the below steps

1. Select your project Data Model file
2. Select "Editor" 7th from the left of the Apple on the menu bar
3. Select "Create NSManagedObject Subclass
4. Check the box next to the Data Model
5. Check the boxes of the entities you want to use
6. Select "Create"

Answer (score 0):

This is because, `NSOrderedSet` doesn't support `Codable` protocol. Instead try using a `Set`.

```
@NSManaged public var devices: Set<String>?
```

You can create a `Set` of data types whatever your app supports.

Comment: then how would you decode the property as Set and return the result in ordered set or array ? Coz i need ordered list of data.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you are using `Set` to get distinct elements. Why don't you filter out the duplicates and store it as an array? It'll solve your purpose of using OrderedSet.

Comment: i'm using set because core data only provides NSSet or NSOrderedSet as its 'To-Many' relationship's entity type.